# CardView in RecyclerView no gap and textview out of layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a CardView that I put inside a recycler view. The card view that I make doesn't have any gap between each other even though I already add margin and padding. also the text is out of the card view.

This is the result of my code, the text is out of the screen and there is no gap between the card view:

[image]

This is the list xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_invoice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="invoice"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="date"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sales_invoice" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/top_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sales_date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sales_itemname_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/item_name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sales_itemqty_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/item_qty"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/sales_itemprice_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sales_itemprice_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/item_price"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/mid_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header" />

        <TextView
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="item"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_qty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="qty"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/sales_itemqty_header"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/sales_itemqty_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sales_itemqty_header" />

        <TextView
            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/price"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/sales_itemprice_header"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/sales_itemprice_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sales_itemprice_header" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

this is the recycler view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SalesHistoryActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_history"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sales_history"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/sales_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sales_history"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below attached code will solve your issue. Hope it will help you. Please try to approve it, if it is useful.

If you have any other question fill free to ask in below comment section. I will try my best to solve that too.

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_invoice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="invoice"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="date"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sales_invoice" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/top_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sales_date" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sales_itemname_header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="item_name"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sales_itemqty_header"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sales_itemqty_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="item_qty"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sales_itemprice_header"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sales_itemprice_header"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Item price"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/sales_itemqty_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/mid_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_type"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/sales_itemname_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mid_line" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_qty"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="qty"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/sales_itemqty_header"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/sales_itemqty_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sales_itemqty_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sales_price"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:text="Rp 13000.00"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/sales_itemprice_header"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/sales_itemprice_header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sales_itemprice_header" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Comment: but the card view still has no gap between each other. do you know why ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use wrap_content in your card.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res       /android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">
 ....
```